# Struggling to get into +EV positions frequently

Tags: pot-odds, ev

I'm fairly new to the game, but I understand the concept of pot odds - however frequently I'm getting into positions where I'm not getting good odds for draws. A recent example:

$0.01/$0.02 - My stack is $3.45.

I'm in the cutoff with A:hearts:Q:diamonds:. The person to my right raises to $0.06. I call. Everyone else folds.
So the pot is $0.14. Flop is J:spades:6:hearts:T:clubs:, opponent bets $0.09.

While I have a very nice straight draw, I'm not getting good enough odds to call here so I fold.

This situation happens to me all the time. Am I missing something here to get the pot to a better size to get better odds? Should I have called in the hand above?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the flop if you believe your `implied odds` are good.

Your `implied odds` are good if:

- Hitting your hand will get you paid a large enough amount later in the hand to outweigh the cost of calling.
- You can bluff your opponent off the best hand frequently enough to outweigh the cost of calling. This is known as `floating`.

Also, you should note that you should be thinking about `pot odds` for the turn only because your opponent can bet the turn.

In this case I believe against an average opponent you would have the correct `implied odds` to call because you have `position` on your opponent. If your opponent checks the turn then there is a reasonable chance they will fold a hand better than yours (22-99) to a turn bet, and of course you can hit your outs to make a better hand.

Answer (score 0):

Some tables just over bet.  Wait for your spot.  When you hit trips or better you are going to get paid off big.

You also have two overs. So unless they have 2 pair or trips you have 10 outs. 
Your pot odd are 23/9 = 2.6 and hand odd (52-5-10)/10 = 3.7.  You are not getting immediate odds to call.

You also have implied odds. If you think you can get more bets when you hit then it may be profitable.

Comment: An 8 or 9 would give you a double gutter